# laravel upload file pdf

Tags: regex, laravel, pdf

i go this view file that only working to upload image types file, need help to make it can do upload different extension of file leets says .doc or .pdf

thank you

controler:

```
public function pengajuan_baru_post()
                if($layanan->dokumenLayanan->count() > 0){
                    if($this->request->has(['dokumen_id', 'dokumen'])){
                        foreach ($this->request->dokumen as $dok) {
                            if(!empty($dok)){
                                if(empty(preg_match('/^data:image\/(?<extension>(?:png|gif|jpg|jpeg|webp));base64,(?<image>.+)$/', $dok))){
                                    return back()->with('warning', 'Pastikan format dokumen yang diupload adalah gambar');
                                }
                            }
                        }
```

Comment: just add the extensions to the regex...

Answer (score 0):

All you really need change is to make `preg_match()` on the desired extensions:

```
preg_match('/^data:file\/(?<extension>(?:doc|docx|pdf)
```

Like this;

```
public function pengajuan_baru_post()
{
    if($layanan->dokumenLayanan->count() > 0){
        if($this->request->has(['dokumen_id', 'dokumen'])){
            foreach ($this->request->dokumen as $dok) {
                if(!empty($dok)){
                    if(empty(preg_match('/^data:file\/(?<extension>(?:doc|docx|pdf));base64,(?<file>.+)$/', $dok))){
                        return back()->with('warning', 'Pastikan format dokumen yang diupload adalah gambar');
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That should do it.

That said, if you're using Laravel you should be using the [Laravel file validation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#quick-writing-the-validation-logic) facilities. This, currently, is a pretty brittle way to do it. Always use the framework, when possible, when using a framework. (AKA don't reinvent the wheel.)